# 'biblatex.sty' not found - although package is installed

Tags: biblatex, packages, ubuntu

When I want to include the `biblatex` package I always get the error-message above. Here are some basic information:

- I'm using Ubuntu 14.04LTS and have installed Texlive with the Ubuntu Software-Center
- The `biblatex.sty` package is installed in: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
- I'm using Texmaker

I already tried to compile the `.tex` file from the terminal and it returns the same error, so I guess it has nothing to do with Texmaker.

I read about 'vanilla' tex but as far as I know `biblatex` is by now included in the recent Texlive-Version of the Ubuntu-Center. I don't need/want more control about my packages and as I mentioned above it indeed is installed, so I don't know if this will help me in any way.

Hopefully you can give me some advice. If I forgot any information please let me know it.

Comment: What (if anything) does `kpsewhcih biblatex.sty` at the Terminal report?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It reports nothing..

Comment: @user3204077: I can hardly imagine, that even a `vanilla` install does omit `biblatex`. Please log in as `root` or use `su` and try `texconfig rehash`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I get back some updating information but am still not able to compile the file.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra`?

Comment: Perhaps there is just an error in your `*.tex` file. Please post a MWE which leads to that error message.

Comment: @egreg This worked for me. Thanks a lot at everyone.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an incomplete TeX distribution, the problem was fixed by installing the appropriate packages (see comment above).

Comment: Same problem here. I am considerably new to LaTeX. In my case I am using Mac and installed the short distro `BasicTex`. Using this tool:  `https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/releases/tag/1.23` it was possible for me to access all the pachages in CTAN and solve this issue.