# How do I extract my own papers from references as a list of publications?

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, biblatex-dw

I'd like to extract my own papers from references as an independent page, say `Publications`.

I following the answer with the highest upvotes from [Including additional bibliography (publication list) in thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97057/including-additional-bibliography-publication-list-in-thesis), however, I encounter the issue `File 'biblatex.sty' not found` at,

```
\usepackage[
    style=numeric-comp,
    bibstyle=numeric,
    sorting=none,
    url=false,
    natbib=true,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex} % Load the package with some options.
\addbibresource{References.bib} % This is your library.
```

As mentioned in the comments of this post ['biblatex.sty' not found - although package is installed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185786/biblatex-sty-not-found-although-package-is-installed), I install `texlive-bibtex-extra` with `sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra`. This issue is gone, but I encounter a new issue `! Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid.`.

---

Here is a MWM.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage[
    style=numeric-comp,
    bibstyle=numeric,
    sorting=none,
    url=false,
    natbib=true,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex} % Load the package with some options.
\addbibresource{References.bib} % This is your library.


\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
Some Text with reference \cite{ICCC15}.

\chapter*{List of publications}

% Print your own papers.
\begin{refsection}
% If you print a bibliography within this section, only citations within this refsection will be printed.

% Option 1: Make nocite for all of your papers.
% Options 2 would be a seperate file which contains all of your papers.
\nocite{ICCC15}
\defbibnote{myPrenote}{Some words before I show you the list of my own papers.}
\defbibnote{myPostnote}{A bunch of papers are still in print and not yet published.}
\printbibliography[
    heading=bibintoc,
    title={Author's Contributions},
    prenote=myPrenote,
    postnote=myPostnote
]
\end{refsection}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

---

**Updated:** As pointed by @PhilipPirrip, I follow the instructions from [biblatex: List of references of own papers in appendix (might intersect with bibliography)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/biblatex-list-of-references-of-own-papers-in-appendix-might-intersect-with-bib), but still got nothing under `List of publications`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[natbib=true, style=numeric-comp, backend=bibtex8,defernumbers, maxnames=99]{biblatex}
\bibliography{References}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
Some Text with reference \cite{ICCC15}.

\chapter*{List of publications}
\begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[keyword=myPapers,title={My papers}, prefixnumbers={P.}, heading=bibnumbered]
\end{refsection}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're mixing bibtex and biblatex. Last two \biblio... commands in your mwe are bibtex.

Comment: Here's how to do it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23379/65222  (keywords + refsection)

Comment: @PhilipPirrip, thx a lot, but I still got nothing. I just updated my question.

Comment: @sparkandshine : here is a [good post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25702/64454) about bibtex vs biblatex (vs natbib), etc.

Comment: @sparkandshine try `\nocite{*}` instead of `\nocite{ICCC15}`

Comment: @ebo, many thanks. I tried it but still got nothing. There is a warning `Package biblatex Warning: Keyword 'myPapers' not found on input line 14.`

Comment: @sparkandshine : silly typo! try `keyword={myPapers}`

Comment: @ebo, doesn't work. It works for me if removing `keyword=myPapers`.

Comment: @sparkandshine so everything is working now? for more info about `\printbibliography` options, consult the [`biblatex` user manual](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), and especially the `§3.7.2 The Bibliography` on page 72.

Comment: @ebo, thx for your constant help. It works, but the format is undesirable. Is it possible to separate my papers into two categories, say `Conference` and  `Journal` under the same section?

Comment: @ebo, I make it with `heading=subbibliography`.

Comment: You have to mark your papers in the .bib database with the same keyword, like in `@ARTICLE{minecited,
    author = {Me},
    title = {Mine -- Cited},
    keywords = {myPapers}
}` you know?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments.